# Cómo cambio la función __str__ para obtener una matriz

Tags: python, python-3.x

resulta que estoy haciendo una práctica para la universidad en la que a partir de un documento de texto como este(un tablero random que nos da el profesor):

1. 4,,,*,
2. 4,,5,,1
3. ,,4,,
4. .,,,,3
5. ,.,,3,

Debemos obtener una matriz de la forma:

1. [4][ ][ ][B][ ]
2. [4][ ][5][ ][1]
3. [ ][ ][4][ ][ ]
4. [R][ ][ ][ ][3]
5. [ ][R][ ][3][3]

Donde se cambian los valores(.) y (*) por letras(en concreto son colores,pues se trata de crear el juego 0hn0).
Así, el código que he escrito es el siguiente:

```
class Dot:
    def __init__(self, color, updatable = True,value = None):
       self.color=color
       self.updatable=updatable
       self.value=value

   def __str__(self):
        if self.color=="Grey":
            return "[G]"
        if self.color=="Red":
            return"[R]"
        if self.color=="Blue":
            if self.value != None:
                return "[(0)]".format(self.value)
            else:
                return"[B]"
class Board:
    def __init__(self ,filename):
        self.board=Board.fromFile(filename) 
    def fromFile(filename):
    board=[]
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            row,tokens=[],line.strip().split(",")
            for t in tokens:
                if t==".":
                    row.append(Dot("Red",False))
                if t=="*":
                    row.append(Dot("Blue",False,int(1)))
                elif t.isdigit():
                    row.append(Dot("Blue",False,int(t)))
            board.append(row)
    return board

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Board{}'.format(self.board)
```

Pero al ejecutar:

```
 tablero=Board('5x5.txt')
 print(tablero)
```

En vez de obtener la matriz deseada obtengo lo siguiente:

```
  Board[[<__main__.Dot object at 0x000002506C55A7F0>, <__main__.Dot object at 0x000002506C55AAC8>], [<__main__.Dot object at 0x000002506C55ACC0>, <__main__.Dot object at 0x000002506C5E4588>, <__main__.Dot object at 0x000002506C5E49E8>], [<__main__.Dot object at 0x000002506C5E4128>], [<__main__.Dot object at 0x000002506C5E46A0>, <__main__.Dot object at 0x000002506C5E4358>], [<__main__.Dot object at 0x000002506C5E4390>, <__main__.Dot object at 0x000002506C5E4208>, <__main__.Dot object at 0x000002506C5E4B38>]]
```

Por tanto si alguien me pudiera arreglar el error que tengo en la función **str**(self)  le estaría eternamente agradecido.Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que **en la implementación del método `__str__` de las listas** (`self.board` es una lista de listas con objetos `Dot` como items) **siempre se llama al método `__repr__` de sus items**. Podrías sobrescribir `__repr__` en la clase `Dot` para que retornara lo mismo que `__str__` pero no es buena idea, dado que va en contra de lo que `__repr__` debe ser.

Para verlo más claro vamos a simplificar tu problema:

```
class Dot:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def __str__(self):
        return f"[{self.color}]"

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Dot({self.color})"
```

> ```
> >>> tablero = [Dot("R"), Dot("B")]
>
> >>> print(tablero)
> [Dot('R'), Dot('B')]
>
> >>> str(tablero([0]))
> [R]
>
> >>> repr(tablero[0])
> Dot('R')
> ```

Podemos ver como se está llamando el método `__repr__` de `Dot` al imprimir la lista, no al método `__str__`.

La solución es simplemente generar tu cadena llamando al método `__str__` de `Dot` explícitamente. Si quieres que te imprima board con un formato parecido al que muestras, podrías hacer algo así:

```
def __str__(self):
    s = "\n".join(f'[{", ".join(str(dot) for dot in row)}]' for row in self.board)
    return s
```

No se que salida quieres exactamente, pero la clave es iterar sobre los puntos y llamar a `Dot().__str__` (`str(Dot())`) para generar la cadena adecuada.

---

### Edición

Si no puedes usar `str()`, `str.join()`, etc , solo concatenando cadenas (lo cual es muy ineficiente) podrías hacer algo así:

```
def __str__(self):
    s = ""
    for row in self.board:
        s += "[ "
        for dot in row:
            s += dot.__str__() + " "
        s += "]\n"
    return s
```

Ten en cuenta de todas formas que la forma que se considera correcta de llamar al método `__str__` de un objeto es mediante el built-in `str`, no directamente.

Comment: Mas o menos obtengo lo que busco,el problema es que trabajo con ciertas cosas que aún no he dado en clase.Si pudiera encontrar la forma de simplemente definir__Str__(self) usando un lenguaje más sencillo sería un puntazo.Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué es exactamente lo que no podrías usar? Los literales de cadena formateados ( `f'{}'`) se puede substituir por `str.format` (que tu ya usas). Luego uso `str.join` y el resto son expresiones generadoras `(str(dot) for dot in row)` que podemos sustituir por ciclos for-in "normales". No me importa dar una versión más "normal" (puede que esa línea no sea lo más legible del mundo XD), solo te pregunto porque si por ejemplo puedes usar `str,join` facilita la construcción de la cadena (además de se más eficiente que si concatenamos)

Comment: lamentablemente str y join no lo hemos visto asique supongo que el profesor me preguntará que de donde me he sacado eso xd.Si pudieras escribirlo en versión más normal como tu dices te lo agradecería muchisimo.Un saludo y muchas gracias por todo

Answer (score 0):

creo el metodo `__str__`  funciona unicamente a la hora de imprimir por pantalla por eso te regresa solo una instancia de la clase `Dot`.

```
class Dot:
    def __init__(self, color, updatable = True,value = None):
       self.color=color
       self.updatable=updatable
       self.value=value

    def __str__(self):
        if self.color=="Grey":
            return "[G]"
        if self.color=="Red":
            return"[R]"
        if self.color=="Blue":
            if self.value != None:
                return "[(0)]".format(self.value)
            else:
                return"[B]"
class Board:
    def __init__(self ,filename):
        self.board=Board.fromFile(filename) 
    def fromFile(filename):
        board=[]
        with open(filename) as f:
            for line in f:
                row,tokens=[],line.strip().split(",")
                for t in tokens:
                    if t==".":
                        row.append(Dot("Red",False).__str__())
                    if t=="*":
                        row.append(Dot("Blue",False,int(1)).__str__())
                    elif t.isdigit():
                        row.append(Dot("Blue",False,int(t)).__str__())
                board.append(row)
        return board

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Board{}'.format(self.board)

tablero=Board('5x5.txt')
print(tablero)
```